# Android best method for storing and retrieving lists of data

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

I need to be able to store a list of many bitmaps with multiple values for each, for instance a string name, a int resource ID and a boolean flag. Because of this I am leaning towards using SQLite to store this data and retrieve what I need into a list on demand. Currently I am handling these bitmap lists by syncing multiple ArrayLists with the values so the nameList, resourceIDList and flagList indexes are synced across. This works but the class I created to create these lists have several hundred items per list and when I need to add a new entry it can be a real pain as I have to update each list. This method also feels sloppy so if anyone can chime in on a better solution I am all ears!

Comment: Create POJO class for binding list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use android sqlite to store and retrieve your data. Then you can conveniently display the retrieved data on the list. Below I have provided some useful links.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: I am currently using the sqllite db for other reasons, i just wanted to make sure I'm not missing some other method that is less obvious but an overall better solution.